# Is there a reduction in performance when passing a large array into a class?

Tags: ruby

I have a class that handles a large array of IDs. I need them to be in Initialize, but will only use them in certain circumstances.

Will instantiating an object with an array of 6 million ids be slower than instantiating an object with an array of 4 ids? (in the scenario where this data is not used)

Comment: Having an array of 6 million objects "just in case" doesn't sound good. Try to load the data lazily, i.e. defer the loading until the data is actually needed.

Comment: I agree, but if the array size doesn't matter in performance, then why shouldn't I do it this way? I'm using async workers so It's the best way (that I can think of)

Comment: I'm puzzled by your choice of the most helpful answer. The creation of the larger array is clearly driving that result.

Comment: My question was regarding instantiating an object with an array. Not creating the array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No matter how big your array. Variables in ruby are references to objects. Which means in both cases you send a pointer, but not real data as a parameter.

```
require 'benchmark/ips'

class A
  def initialize(arr)
    @arr = arr
  end

  def mutate
    @arr[0] = 11 # once this code been launched, it will change original object.
  end
end

# Do not create test data in the bench!
big_one = 6_000_000.times.map { |_| rand(10)}
small_one = [1,2,3,4]

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.report do
    A.new(big_one)
  end

  x.report do
    A.new(small_one)
  end

  x.compare!
end
```

So, result:

```
Warming up --------------------------------------
                       125.218k i/100ms
                       128.972k i/100ms
Calculating -------------------------------------
                          3.422M (± 0.7%) i/s -     17.155M in   5.014048s
                          3.485M (± 0.5%) i/s -     17.540M in   5.033405s
```

Note: you cannot use methods like #to_a in the benchmark, (1..6_000_000) range conversion to array is a slow operation, which is affect on final score.

Comment: Right, pushing the `#to_a` call outside means that you're benchmarking only the `A.new` call.

Comment: Oh, ok! That's great. (I was personally hoping this would be the case :D )

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is bad for performance. To prove this, I created this test, where I made a class with an instance variable for the ids. I then ran a simple unrelated method adding a number to itself.

```
require 'benchmark/ips'

class TestSize
  def initialize(ids)
    @ids = ids
  end

  def simple_task(n)
    n + n
  end
end

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.report('4 ids') do
    test = TestSize.new((1..4).to_a)
    test.simple_task(3)
  end
  x.report('6 million') do
    test = TestSize.new((1..6_000_000).to_a)
    test.simple_task(3)
  end
  x.compare!
end
```

Here are the results

```
Warming up --------------------------------------
               4 ids   112.545k i/100ms
           6 million     1.000  i/100ms
Calculating -------------------------------------
               4 ids      1.557M (± 5.0%) i/s -      7.766M in   5.001166s
           6 million      5.947  (± 0.0%) i/s -     30.000  in   5.077560s

Comparison:
               4 ids:  1557013.9 i/s
           6 million:        5.9 i/s - 261822.49x  slower
```

So you can see it is much slower, and using much more memory.

I use benchmark-ips all the time to test ideas like this. https://github.com/evanphx/benchmark-ips

I'm running OSX 10.12.6, ruby 2.4.1p111

Comment: That's a great answer. Thanks for your help

Comment: You really should move the `(1..6_000_000).to_a` outside what you're benchmarking. Otherwise you're really benchmarking the `Range#to_a` call rather than the `TestSize.new`. [Med](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45872134/479863) is getting far more useful results from their benchmarking.